# redis connection issue while connecting to redis

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, redis-cluster

There is no issue while testing at stage or prod env, however, while testing at qa1-4, I met this log:

```
07:47:38.303 [http-nio-8001-exec-5] ERROR c.j.s.e.h.RestExceptionHandler - PUT /admin/api/secured/serviceArea/county/13095 ~> 500
org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ClusterCommandExecutionFailureException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ClusterCommandExecutor.collectResults(ClusterCommandExecutor.java:271)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ClusterCommandExecutor.executeCommandAsyncOnNodes(ClusterCommandExecutor.java:214)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ClusterCommandExecutor.executeCommandOnAllNodes(ClusterCommandExecutor.java:176)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClusterConnection.keys(JedisClusterConnection.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor165.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.CloseSuppressingInvocationHandler.invoke(CloseSuppressingInvocationHandler.java:57)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy410.keys(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache$RedisCacheCleanByPrefixCallback.doInLock(RedisCache.java:741)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache$RedisCacheCleanByPrefixCallback.doInLock(RedisCache.java:716)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache$LockingRedisCacheCallback.doInRedis(RedisCache.java:663)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:207)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:169)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:157)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.clear(RedisCache.java:288)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doClear(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:111)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.performCacheEvict(CacheAspectSupport.java:470)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.processCacheEvicts(CacheAspectSupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:418)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:324)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy165.setServiceAreaCounty(Unknown Source)
    at org.rex.controller.admin.secured.servicearea.AdminServiceAreaMaintCommandController.setCountyStatus(AdminServiceAreaMaintCommandController.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:664)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.rex.secure.filter.RexAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RexAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.rex.secure.filter.RexPlatformValidationFilter.doFilter(RexPlatformValidationFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.rex.secure.filter.LoadBalancerHeaderFilter.doFilter(LoadBalancerHeaderFilter.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.rex.secure.filter.VisitorHeaderFilter.doFilter(VisitorHeaderFilter.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:167)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:41)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ClusterCommandExecutor.convertToDataAccessException(ClusterCommandExecutor.java:347)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ClusterCommandExecutor.executeCommandOnSingleNode(ClusterCommandExecutor.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ClusterCommandExecutor.executeCommandOnSingleNode(ClusterCommandExecutor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ClusterCommandExecutor$1.call(ClusterCommandExecutor.java:209)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ClusterCommandExecutor$1.call(ClusterCommandExecutor.java:205)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:202)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:151)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:215)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:340)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:276)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.keys(BinaryJedis.java:357)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClusterConnection$2.doInCluster(JedisClusterConnection.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClusterConnection$2.doInCluster(JedisClusterConnection.java:202)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ClusterCommandExecutor.executeCommandOnSingleNode(ClusterCommandExecutor.java:137)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:196)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
07:47:38.303 [http-nio-8001-exec-5] INFO  c.j.s.e.h.ErrorMessageRestExceptionHandler - No message found for java.lang.Exception.type, nor default.type
07:47:38.303 [http-nio-8001-exec-5] INFO  c.j.s.e.h.ErrorMessageRestExceptionHandler - No message found for java.lang.Exception.title, nor default.title
07:47:38.303 [http-nio-8001-exec-5] INFO  c.j.s.e.h.ErrorMessageRestExceptionHandler - No message found for java.lang.Exception.detail, nor default.detail
07:47:38.303 [http-nio-8001-exec-5] INFO  c.j.s.e.h.ErrorMessageRestExceptionHandler - No message found for java.lang.Exception.instance, nor default.instance
```

The weird thing is sometimes I saw this error log, sometimes I don't, the feature is not stable. I am thinking about 3 reasons made this happen.

1. Not enough memory allocated to qa redis.
2. response time is too short, maybe I should extend maximum allowed response time?
3. redis version is not the most updated.

Any suggestion how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to upgrade your Spring Data Redis and Jedis library's version to the latest versions.

This seems to have been a reoccuring problem in earlier versions of jedis and they have resolved the bug.

Kindly see the
https://github.com/redis/jedis/issues/1977

https://github.com/redis/jedis/issues/1561

==== Edited ===

It depends first on what version of Spring you are using.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: how to upgrade the integrated Spring Data Redis and Jedis library's version at springboot?